# How to add quotes around each word in a string from simplehtmldom

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I am trying to grab the contents of specific tags by class from a web page, turn to plain text, and wrap each word with double quotes.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://linktosite.com');
foreach ( $html->find('.table tr td.span8') as $element ) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```

This outputs the text inside each table->tr->td.span8 onto new lines.

I would like to take the text from each instance, and wrap each individual word in quotes and separate by commas like this:

from:

> wrap each word with quotes and separate with comma

to:

> "wrap", "each", "word", "with", "quotes", "and", "separate", "with", "comma"

I would also like to take it a step further, and only include specific words that I specify in the output.  I will be getting text from a page with about 200 entries, and I want $element->plaintext to only show the words in a variable I set.

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://linktosite.com');
foreach ( $html->find('.table tr td.span8') as $element )
{
    echo ' "' .$element->plaintext. '", <br /> ';
}
```

**EDITED**: forgot to add the comma.

Comment: That won't work because the text in table->tr->td.span8 is a sentence.  I want to wrap each individual word in the sentence in quotes, not the entire sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$res ='';
foreach ( $html->find('.table tr td.span8') as $element ) {
  $res .= '"'.str_replace(" ", '", "',$element->plaintext ).'", ';
}

echo substr($res,0,-2);
```